# Change a page name and url in laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I need to change the page name in my laravel project. I need a help

page name
**about ** to **best-courier-company-in-uae**

like this in the url.

about is a blade file with html inside.
can we change this page name without running the artisan?

i tried to change the name from web.php routing but its not changing.

`Route::redirect('/about', '/best-courier-company-in-uae', 301);

Route::get('/best-courier-company-in-uae', function () {
return view('about');
});`

Comment: All route files are cached in Laravel. You can try to remove `bootstrap/cache` folder contents and see if anything changes.

Comment: I removed the cache folder as u said but then an error came "bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable"

Comment: No, I said contents.
Recreate it and try again. Laravel caches routes into route.php in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mention the route `/best-courier-company-in-uae` is defined after the redirection, so put it before the redirect route

It may be works, Thanks later

Answer (score 0):

I changed the page name url from routes cache into the new name and it worked.
redirect from htaccess old url into new url. add redirect from routes file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wqnq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).